# Which PAAS providers have marketplaces for paid 3rd party add-ons?

Tags: paas

Although not strictly programming, it's surely related.

I'm looking for a decent list of [paas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) (platform as a service) providers that have a marketplace/ecosystem on which consumers can opt to subscribe to 3rd party add-ons, such as mail as a service, mongodb as a service, etc.

Thusfar I come up with only 2:

- [Heroku](https://addons.heroku.com/)
- [Engine Yard](https://www.engineyard.com/partners/platform-services)

Any more?

Comment: CloudBees does too, not sure if OpenShift also has started marketplace recently. CloudFoundry has one in pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon has a [marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/).

Azure has also a (new) [marketplace](http://datamarket.azure.com/about).

Comment: didn't know amaon/aws had one, although I've been using it for years! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party but you want to take a look at this: http://paasify.it

This PaaS comparison and vendor matching is backed up by open source profiles where 3rd party add-ons are explicitly modeled. For now, these PaaS vendors are e.g. *AppHarbor, cloudControl, CloudFoundry, AppFog, CloudBees, EngineYard, Heroku, Nodejitsu.*